# Show PleaseWait Popup in Catel Orchestra + MahApps.Metro

Tags: mahapps.metro, catel

I am trying to show a PleaseWait popup in a Orchestra app the same way it is shown in Catel without Orchestra but im unable to do so.
I know that the PleaseWaitService shows the progress and text in a status bar on the bottom of the window, but is does orchestra have something similar to what Catel has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that we replace the default Catel one by the Orchestra one. We do this for 2 reasons:

1. It's less intrusive (use the mouse cursor instead of a full blocking animation)
2. We support progress notifications in the bottom of the app (again, less intrusive).

If you want to use the old one, you must "re-overwrite" the registration in the service locator:

```
var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;

serviceLocator.RegisterType<IPleaseWaitService, Catel.Services.PleaseWaitService>();
```